# Using SSO with TFS release management

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, tfs-2015, release-management

I am currently trying to create a release to a windows server from TFS 2015. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to pass my user credentials from TFS to the server I need to access without hardcoding them into the release arguments. The way I hope to have it work is that whenever a user queues a new release, their credentials are used for the server login. If they aren't in the correct AD group for the server, the release should fail.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way to pass user credentials from TFS to the server. You may create a test account for the server, and use this single test account for deployment. Then define it under configuration variables in your release definition:

[image]

In this way, you can use these values in the steps instead of typing them:

[image]